# Не запускается файл php

Tags: php

Всем привет! У меня такая проблема!
Хочу с `cmd` строки запустить `php` файл!

> D:\server\php\php.exe -f  D:\www\dbf\index.php

Если запущу с браузера, то он работает! А если с `cmd`, пишет, что не знает функцию `dbase_open()`. `php` скрипт такой:

```
$dbh = dbase_open("bnk.dbf",2);
```

Как сделать так, чтоб `cmd` знал эту функцию??))))

Comment: Сменить директорию. Иначе запуск идет не из того места, где лежит файл, соответственно, библиотеки он найти свои не может.

Comment: сменить директорию файла?

Comment: Пишет ошибку:Warning: dbase_open(): unable to open database ../bnk.dbf in D:\WWW\dbf\index.ph
p on line 13 в командной строке

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$dbh = dbase_open("bnk.dbf",2);
```

- вот тут укажите полный путь к базе.